# Is it possible to make static C++ library self contained?

Tags: c++, c

If my library has external dependencies is it possible to include those libraries to my own static library, that users of my library wouldn't need to link to those dependencies? Or should I make it dynamic library?

library.h

```
#ifndef AMAZING_CPP_LIBRARY_H
#define AMAZING_CPP_LIBRARY_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
    int m_code;
} Result;

extern void message(const char* msg);

extern Result * get_result();

extern void vector_example(int size);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif //AMAZING_CPP_LIBRARY_H
```

library.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "library.h"

void vector_example(int size){
    std::vector<uint8_t> vec;
    vec.reserve(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    // do something with vector
}

void message(const char* msg) {
    std::cout << msg<< "\n";
}

Result * get_result() {
    Result* result = new Result();
    result->m_code = 200;
    return result;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "library.h"

int main() {
    vector_example(2);
    message("hello from cpp");
    return 0;
}
```

Commands I'm running

```
1$ clang++ -c library.cpp
2$ ar -rcs libamazing_cpp.a library.o
3$ clang -c main.c 
4$ clang main.o libamazing_cpp.a
```

Is it possible to compile with just linking to my static library, without needing to use `-lstdc++` or using `clang++` command?

Comment: Why? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: A static library (`.a`) is nothing more than a collection of object files (the "a" stands for "archive"). So no, not possible. You could bundle the relevant libstdc++ objects, but they will conflict with the shared libstdc++ later on.

Comment: @rustyx: Having copies of library object modules in earlier libraries does not create conflicts. The linker takes a module from a library only if it defines a symbol not yet defined by object modules already taken. So, when it encounters a duplicate module in a later library, it simply ignores it.

Comment: https://github.com/intoli/exodus

Comment: You couch the question in terms specifically of avoiding linking the C++ standard library, but you seem to be overlooking some important details. For example, the fact most C++ compilers don't require you to explicitly link the C++ standard library anyway, and that if you don't use a C++ compiler to build C++ programs then you open yourself to all manner of misbehavior related to the C++ environment not being set up correctly at runtime.  I'm inclined to think that the best possible result of doing what you have in mind is that it just doesn't make anything worse.  If you're lucky.

Comment: @JohnBollinger stdC++ was just example library. What if `my_library` depends on `library_A` and it depends on `library_B` and `library_C`, users of `my_library` will need to link to all 4 libraries? That's how c/c++ works?

Comment: @RacNor, to the extent that your interest is in avoiding users linking *third party* dependencies then that's a somewhat different story, and the last part of the question is a red herring.  But the answer is probably still "don't do that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make static C++ library self contained?

### This is implementation specific, and could be sometimes illegal.

Notice that most C++ standards (read e.g. [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) don't even mention libraries (in particular, related to your compiler, e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and to its standard C++ library `libstdc++`)

But your C++ library would probably use standard C++ [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (part of the C++ standard) or other opensource C++ libraries like [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [FLTK](https://fltk.org/) whose license may require your user to be able to upgrade them.

**Be sure to contact your lawyer**, since there could be legal aspects in your question related to software licenses.

#### On Linux, it would be inefficient

If you target Linux, you want to take advantage of *existing* shared libraries (as listed by [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), or -if you have a running process- by [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html)). Read Drepper's paper [*How to write shared libraries*](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf) for details and explanations, and consider making your library a shared one.

> `clang++ -c library.cpp`

Hint: use at least `clang++ -c -Wall -Wextra -g library.cpp` then use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to debug your library, and try also `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g library.cpp` and use also [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).

To ease installation (or testing) of your library on Linux systems, you may want to provide a [package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) for it. On [Debian](https://debian.org/), it would be some `*.deb` file.

Comment: What if `my_library` only works with `library_V1` but user has `library_V2` will he need to downgrade/download another version of that lib? Another case `library_V1` is not available on his platform. Will he need to compile it himself?

Comment: It depends. Probably yes. But if your `*.deb` package is correctly written (not an easy task) the `dpkg` command installing it would take care of such dependencies. Consider publishing the C++ code (and the packaging scripts) of your library with some [open source licence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) or even better as [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), like [GNU readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/) is. You could need approval from your manager, then perhaps get help from outside contributors.